# How do you check if DateTime is initialized?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, datetime, timer

I need help with making a code that checks every second if Datetime is started.
If it is started it should close the already running function.
I know dispatchertimer but I want it to run the thread in background.
The reason is because I have a mediaplayer that plays till datetime is started, causing the movie to restart every 1 second.

I would be very thank full if you guys could help me, a little bit desperate...

```
        Dictionary<string, string> listBox3Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private bool listbox3job()
        {
            AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp =
wfh.Child as AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer;
            DateTime? start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
            DateTime? end = DateTimePicker2.Value; // This. End date. If end date. Stop movie.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if (start == null || end == null)
            {
            }
            else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
                {
                    foreach (var selected in listBox3.Items)
                    {
                        string s = selected.ToString();

                        if (listBox3Dict.ContainsKey(s))
                        {
                            axWmp.URL = (listBox3Dict[s]);
                        }
                    }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `if Datetime is started`, what in the world does that mean?

Comment: Generate a thread and loop in the background...

Comment: DateTime is a function.i specify DateTime to start at 2 pm and do stuff.

Comment: so you have a monitor thread and you want to start a function call in another thread if it isn't already running.  If it's already running, you want to kill the running thread and start a new one?  Is that even close?  Note: System.DateTime is a time holding class.

Comment: @bash.d
How? I'm not very good at this at all.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You'd know the answer to that question if time wasn't stopped.

Comment: I think he means if `DateTime.Now` changed.

Comment: @Sneakybastardd, do you have access to create a Scheduled Task on the server or machine you're going to run this on?

Comment: meh I can show you a example.
Editing now

Comment: "meh I can show you a example" -> "I guess i'll put effort into helping you solve my problem"

Comment: @Sneakybastardd, is there a really compelling reason you can't leverage an event on the date time picker?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud
The movie starts fine at DateTime Start.
I want it to stop at DateTime stop.

Comment: @Sneakybastardd, and what control are you using to play the movie?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud
I'm using AxWindowsMediaPlayer :)

Comment: In your example you're not *doing* anything besides asigning three values to three variables. Please show us the code where you're actually *work* with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, against my better judgment, I'm going to provide you a solution that will let you check the value every second. The **only reason I'm providing this solution** is because the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` object does not have an event that is fired as playback occurs. You're going to need to build a `BackgroundWorker` to do this:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // here you will check the time
    while (end > DateTime.Now)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

and when you're ready to use the `BackgroundWorker` you'll issue this:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

however, I'm making some assumptions because you really didn't put enough effort into your question. I'm assuming that you want to check the ending time against `DateTime.Now` because you declared all of those variables. I've also seen a similar question on here today - performing just about the same operation. The other reason I'm making that assumption is because the control you're using doesn't really provide you a good mechanism to determine the current playback location of the media file.

In the future, please put a lot more effort into your questions. Remember, we know **nothing** about what you're doing and so it's verify difficult to provide a solution without any context. I know you're probably busy, and you feel like you're under a crunch, but providing us with little to no information isn't going to speed up the process - as you can see from the comments thread.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.

Been on quite bad mood because of limited time and I'm sorry.

Comment: @Sneakybastardd, no worries. We've all been there. I just wanted to help you understand where we are coming from.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't use a timer for this, rather than a sleeping thread?

Comment: @Jim, very good question, and I have to say I clearly could have used that implementation. I think moving forward I'll default to that in situations like this. Thanks for the direction!